# WCF on cloud is not working

Tags: wcf, azure, cloud

I just created a WCF service and deployed in one of the machine's IIS and checked it works fine.
When I deploy the same service on Cloud VM's IIS I am not able to consume that service.
I am getting the error saying that "There is no listener with the endpoint".

Can i deploy normal WCF on cloud or do i need to create WCF cloud service?

Environment(IIS 8.5)

Comment: What bindings are you using? Do you have endpoints configured for this cloud service?

Answer (score 0):

It could be several Things, most probably:

- ASP.net not activated on IIS

Also check:

- The url you are using
- firewall problems
- site not started